# Get a point on a plane at specific distance from initial point

Tags: python, sympy

I got this plane

```
from sympy.geometry.plane import Plane
p=Plane((0,5,0),(0,0,0),(5,7,0)) #2d first to make it easier
```

now I want to get a point on that plane 45deg from plane point one and lenght=sqrt(2). In this case that point will be (1,6,0)

I've tried this:

```
a=np.sqrt(2)*p.arbitrary_point(pi/4)
```

but it does not work as a coordinates return (1.0,8.07106781187,0.0)
the problem is that arbitrary_point returns a point in a circle of radius 1 about p1 of the Plane. I want to be able to change that radius.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Multiplying all of a point's coordinates by sqrt(2) moves it away from the origin (0,0,0). You want to move it away from p1 of the plane. This is what the [scale](http://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/geometry/points.html#sympy.geometry.point.Point3D.scale) method is for.

```
p.arbitrary_point(np.pi/4).scale(np.sqrt(2), np.sqrt(2), np.sqrt(2), p.p1)
```

returns `Point3D(1, 6, 0)`.

(I'm assuming `import numpy as np` here, to match the setting of the question; the standard `math` module could be used instead of numpy.)

Comment: Thanks, it works great. Do you happen to know any other way to calculate this sort of things without sympy?. This method fails in difficult planes like this one:
Plane((2.3781456548404956, -2.2550177749815092, 2.6342732531317825),(2.99886542037, -2.85419098704, 0.0),(5.88736572126, 1.36829542036, 2.5))